# Pandas distribute columns to disjoint groups by triplets in rows

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe with booleans, where each line has at least three Trues and each column at least one True, I need to distribute the columns to N disjoint groups with at least three columns in each group if it possible.

For example N = 2

Dataframe:

```
        a      b     c     d      e      f
0     False  True  True  True   False  False
1     True   False True  True   True   True
2     False  False True  False  True   True
```

The only possible result: b,c,d and a,e,f

In larger data frames may be more than one solution, I need any one of the solutions. Columns may be skipped if it is required for solution, but preferred to use as much as possible columns. The resulted groups can be with any size, but not less than three. For example 3 groups with sizes 9, 3, 11 is a valid result for N=3 and dataframe with 30 columns.

An example of dataframe, where the distribution is impossible (Reset e1 in the example above)

```
        a      b     c     d      e      f
0     False  True  True  True   False  False
1     True   False True  True   False  True
2     False  False True  False  True   True
```

Comment: My math is failing, and judging by the time with no answers everyone else's is too... can you explain how to make a disjoint group? How do you get "b,c,d and a,e,f"?

Comment: Sure. Lets look in every line in the table and choose all Trues.

0 b c d
1 a c d e f
2 c e f

Lets look for sets with size at least 3.
0 {b, c, d}
1 {a, c, d, e, f}, {a, c, d, e}, {a, c, d, f}, {a, c, e, f}, ..., {c, d, e, f}, {a, c, d}, {a, c, e}, ..., {a, e, f}, ..., {d, e, f}
2 {c, e, f}

Since N=2 wee look for two biggest sets with an empty intersection between them, i.e. disjoint sets. In this example the only possible solution is b,c,d from index 0 and a,e,f from index 1

Comment: My goal is to distribute servers with different devices to disjoint storage units. Each storage unit should have at least three servers. The system should be balanced, so servers should contribute at least 3 devices from the same size. Each column in my table represents a server. Each line represents devices with different size and type. The value is True if the server has the device.

Comment: at a glance it seems to me you could solve this with [dancing links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X)... look around, there are many examples solving sudoku and other exact cover problems... yours is an exact cover problem in the sense that all rows need to be "covered" by at least 3 columns, you might find several solutions and perhaps you can further optimize on load/utilization

Comment: I will try this approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used RichieV's suggestion and resolved the issue with [dancing links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X).

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import List, Tuple, Set
from itertools import combinations


def distribute_columns_by_triplets(df: pd.DataFrame, group_num: int,
        result: List[Tuple[str]], tested: Set[Tuple[str]] = None) -> bool:
    if not group_num:
        return True

    if not df.shape[0]:
        return False

    if df.shape[1] < 3 * group_num:
        return False

    if tested is None:
        tested = set()

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        positives = row[row].index
        for i in range(positives.size, 2, -1):
            current = combinations(positives, i)
            for combination in current:
                if combination in tested:
                    continue

                tested.add(combination)

                if distribute_columns_by_triplets(df.drop(columns=list(combination)),
                        group_num - 1, result, tested):
                    result.append(combination)
                    return True

        df.drop(index, inplace=True)

    return False


d = {
    'a': [False, True, False],
    'b': [True, False, False],
    'c': [True, True, True],
    'd': [True, True, False],
    'e': [False, True, True],
    'f': [False, True, True],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['device_number'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df.sort_values(by='device_number', inplace=True)
df.drop('device_number', axis=1, inplace=True)

group_num = 2

result = []
if distribute_columns_by_triplets(df.copy(), group_num, result):
    print(result)
else:
    print('Failed')
```